# Twitter Bootstrap Popovers dynamic HTML from $.get()

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

```
 $('#editPersonal').popover({
        trigger: 'click',
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        content: function () {
            var url = "/Profile/Edit"; // the url to the controller
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            var res = "";
           **return  $.get(url + '/' + id, data)**
        }           
        });
```

How to return HTML from $.get method to popover ?
 **return  $.get(url + '/' + id, data)** is not working am in missing on any syntax or this is not the right way to do this ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

yay, i got it solved myself , the following code is working for me

```
 <div id="editPersonal"
                             class="btn btn-lg btn-danger"
                             data-toggle="popover"
                             data-html=true 
                             data-id="@Model.Id">Hover to toggle popover</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#editPersonal').popover({

        trigger: 'click',
        placement: 'bottom',
        html: true,
        content: function () {

            var p = $(this);
            var url = "/Profile/Edit";
            var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
            $.get(url + '/' + id, function (data) {
                p.attr("data-content", data);
                p.popover('show');
            });


        }
    });
```